# Swift - Update variable inside view Controller from Tab Bar Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, parameter-passing

I need to update a variable in a View Controller and I need to do that from a Tab Bar Controller.

See image below:
[image]

I have tried so many different code but, since i implemented a Navigation Controller in between, none of them is working.

Code1

```
let myVC:MyViewController = self.viewControllers?[0] as MyViewController
myVC.x = "marco"
```

Code2

```
var storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
var myVC:MyViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("view2") as MyViewController
myVC.x = "marco"
```

Code3

```
let myInstance:MyViewController = MyViewController()
myInstance.x = "marco"
```

But none of them is working.
Help please

Thank you very much

Comment: Look at your structure. What is the root view controller in the first tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to follow the view controller hierarchy from your tab bar controller down to your custom view controller, like this:

> Tab bar controller (self) -> navigation controller -> custom view controller

We want to get the tab bar controller's first view controller (a navigation controller), and then get that navigation controller's first view controller. In code, you can do it this way:

```
let myVC = (self.viewControllers?[0] as UINavigationController).viewControllers[0] as MyViewController
myVC.x = "marco"
```

Note that this is brittle, and will fail if you change the hierarchy at all.

Comment: Fantastic! it works!! I noticed this is really brittle, but is this the only way to do it right? Thank you very much!

Comment: i have same problem in a different scenario. Could you please help me with that?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533449/swift-update-a-variable-in-a-tableviewcontroller