# Update a variable in a TableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, parameter-passing

I need to update a variable in a TableViewController and I can't find the way to do it, can someone explain me why this is not working please?
I'm getting mad.

[image]

From my view controller this is the code I'm running:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let TV = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tbController") as myTableViewController
TV.x = "test"
```

And then, from the TableViewController class:

```
class myTableViewController: UITableViewController {
 var x:String!
 override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     println("Value of x is: \(self.x)")
 }
}
```

And the printed value is: nil

Why? What is wrong with that? I don't understand :-(

***Updated Picture***
[image]

Comment: How is your TV presented?

Comment: You're creating a new instance of myTableViewController (with let TV = storyboard ...), and that's not the one you have on screen. I can't tell from your image what the connection is between ViewController and the navigation controller. You need to describe your controller setup, and how you get the navigation controller on screen.

Comment: @pbasdf: im able to access the variable x. The editor is displaying it as soon as I write "TV."

Comment: @rdelmar: There is no connection between the view controller and the navigation controller. Actually the line you see it's just a simple push segue from the "Button" to the Table View Controller. Do I have to change it?

Comment: Sure, but as @rdelmar points out, it looks like you are creating a new instance of your table view controller, not accessing an existing one.  Show the code for displaying the table view TV.

Comment: Well, you can't do a push segue if ViewController itself is not embedded in a navigation controller. If the navigation controller you show isn't connected, why do you have it there?

Comment: And also show us your `prepareForSegue` code in the first view controller.

Comment: @pbasdf I have no code to display the table view, I have only created a push segue from the button that you can see in the view controller to the table view controller. I have done that just using the Storyboard, CTRL drag from the button to the Table View Controller. is that a problem?

Comment: I have just added a new picture at the end of the question, to make you understand better the storyboard. Thank you

Comment: I think @rdelmar is right.  When you push the button in your first view controller, the segue will automatically create an instance of the table view controller where X IS nil.  Your other code is creating a new and unrelated version - which is not presented on screen and so viewDidLoad is not executed, so no log message

Comment: Thanks @pbasdf, I do understand your point, but how can I update a variable in that table view controller if it has not been instantiated yet?

Comment: That's where `prepareForSegue` comes in - it will give you a reference to the VC it has instantiated so you can set any properties you need to.  Search the docs or in SO.

Comment: THANKS!!!! I JUST USED THAT!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, give the segue between the ViewController and the TableViewController an identifier (Example: "TableViewSegue"

Then in the ViewController, use `prepareForSegue` to pass data from ViewController to TableViewController

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
// Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    if segue.identifier == "TableViewSegue" {
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as myTableViewController
        vc.x = "Test"
    }
}
```

Comment: A.M.A.Z.I.N.G. Finally i understand how to use this prepareForSegue!!!!!!!!!!! THANKS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

There could be several issues here.

*1. You should embed the tableview into the initial viewcontroller and create it as an IBOutlet*

*Edit: from the updated picture it appears that you want to click the top right button and go to the tableview. Therefore, this is an incorrect statement.*

2. You also need to make your Viewcontroller (either the tableviewcontroller or the main viewcontroller if you chose to follow #1 above) a UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource
3. If you are expecting to change the label listed on the image shown, you will need to use label.text = "String" assignment to change what is displayed there
4. You have not set an initial variable for x inside the tableviewcontroller.

Also, as a point, your order of operations isn't properly set, so it will always display nil. Because if you look at how you built this:

1. You have a println inside of a viewdidload on the tableview. This variable you are printing has NOT been set yet, so it is nil
2. You then created an instance of this class. As soon as you created that instance, the viewdidload method fired and it printed a nil line.
3. THEN you changed the variable via the TV.x method. But there is no println check there so you're not able to see what you did.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm trying to follow your advices.
1. /
2. I have edited the class TableViewController as you suggested: class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDelegate { ... But I'm not able to make it a UITableViewDataSource as i get an error "Type MyTableViewController does not conform to protocol UITableViewDataSource'
3. I'm not changing a label, I just need to set a value to a string variable
4. I set up a initial value for the variable and when I'm printing it It's printing the initial value, it means the view controller is still not updating it

Comment: The "Does not conform to protocol error" is a result of you not using the required methods when creating a tableview. You can hold Command and highlight UITableViewDataSource to see the required functions to make it conform.

Comment: I have tried the command functionality. Really interesting, thanks @Ricky Wainwright